# How do you determine if an occurrence in a subset is significant.

Tags: probability, analysis, statistical-inference

There are roughly $22,000$ genes.
I have $1,200$ genes randomly chosen from the 22K in Group $A$.
I have $80$ genes in Group $B$ randomly chosen from the 22k.

How do I determine the probability of at least $2$ genes from group $B$ appearing in group $A$?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Are we to assume that the genes in each of the two groups are chosen uniformly from, the entire $22,000$?  Do you mean exactly two or at least two?

Comment: The two groups are chosen independently of each other. You are taken a random set from the 22,000. And I mean at least 2.

Comment: And uniformly, I assume.  Can you, say, compute the probability that no $B-$genes are in $A$?

Comment: Yes I guess I would like to be able to determine the probability of 0, 1, 2, 3, etc..

Comment: I am asking if you know how to compute the probability that no $B-$genes are in $A$.

Comment: May be worth noting:  the problem is fairly easy if you ignore the dependence between the genes (knowing that the first $A$ gene is also a $B$ gene changes the probability for the next one, slightly).  Then it's just a binomial process.  Decent approximation, not great.

Comment: I don't it's been about 20 years since I've taken statistics. My guess roughly ((1,200 / 22,000) * (80 / 22,000))^2 would be the probability of finding 2 genes from B in A.

Comment: For $0$:  There are $\binom {22000}{1200}$ ways to choose the $A-$genes and there are $\binom {22000}{1120}$ ways to choose them from the non $B-$genes.  The answer you seek is the ratio.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yeah I'm confused here by what you mean in the parentheses. Is that 22,000 / 1200 or are you saying there are 22,000 x 1200 ways to chose A genes?

Comment: Those are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  I posted something below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the $B-$genes are chosen. For a fixed $i$ the probability that the $A-$genes contain exactly $i$ $B-$genes is $$P_i=\frac {\binom {80}i\times \binom {22000-80}{1200-i}}{\binom {22000}{1200}}$$

The answer you seek is $$1-P_0-P_1\approx 0.9371388$$

So it is extremely likely that you'll have at least $2$ $B-$genes amongst the $A's$.

Worth noting that the probability that any given $A-$gene is also in $B$ is $\frac {80}{22000}$ so the expected number of $A-$genes in $B$ is $$\frac {80}{22000}\times 1200\approx 4.36$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to read up more to understand what you are doing here. Do you have a recommended reference? I'm surprised by the outcome. You're saying that it's close to a 100% chance that at least 2 genes would be found from group B in group A?

Comment: Well, it's about $94\%$.    I like the [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Probability) for an introduction to the basics.    If you can program at all, you can run a simulation.  Without loss of generality, assume that $B=\{1,\cdots, 80\}$.  Then choose $1200$ numbers randomly from $\{1,\cdots , 22000\}$.  You should easily confirm that you almost always get at least $2$.

Comment: Cool. I can program so I'll try that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Simulation is an excellent way to attack probability problems.  Sure, exact methods are better when they are available but they are often unavailable or more trouble than they are worth.